# Execute all the stored procedures in the database with dummy input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL query (no matter how big it will become) to execute all the stored procedures present in the database with dummy input parameters. Basically, my intention is to check whether my all stored procedures are working or not if all the parameters provided correctly. Can anyone please help me with this?

I tried getting all the stored procedures name along with its no. of parameters, parameter type. Not able to understand how should I proceed with dummy parameters with nos. of stored procedures coming on the way one by one.

I want to execute all the stored procedures one by one present in my database with dummy input parameters. I just need to verify that my all the stored procedures are working correctly with dummy input parameters. If I am getting any error I just log it in another table.

Comment: How are *we* supposed to know what a valid dummy parameter is, when we have no idea about your database? This sounds like a job for a tester, or **well maintained** automated testing system; which will need you to tell it what good (and bad) parameters are for your objects.

Comment: But how are you going to verify a stored procedure is "working" if you give it data that it may well not be able to process (because it violates constraints or otherwise covers scenarios it was never intended to handle)? Just randomly calling everything is very unlikely to yield any meaningful insight. That only confirms the procedure exists and is invokable in some fashion, but you already know that.

Comment: Concretely, suppose you wanted to test the `DeleteCustomer` procedure, which takes an `@ID` and is supposed to set the `IsDeleted` column to `1`. Calling this procedure with a random ID is most likely to not have any effect at all (because the row is not in the table) and even when it does have an effect, you can only know this by actually checking the column. A dummy invocation would tell you nothing about whether the procedure does any meaningful work.

Comment: @Larnu we do not have to worry about our parameter dummy values here, as I am just checking whether my procedure is working or not without throwing any exception.

Comment: I agree to your point, in such case I want my procedure to throw proper error. which means I just want to check whether my procedures did not encountered any exception. Also, the reason I want to log this errors in separate table is only because I can fix those error(like how suggested) later manually.

Comment: I have a script I use regularly to check dependencies.  So that if the stored procedure references an invalid table or view, it will get logged.  It will not check the logic of the procedure, but it does check all of the other referenced objects.  If you're interested, I can post that as an answer.

Comment: @RobertSievers cud u pls share dt script here, I thnk u gt my point & dat is the thing I am actually loking for. So, here is the thing:- my SP uses many DB's. After few years later, the DB's hav been moved to difrnt servers. Now my SP r breaking cos the DB is nt prsnt in current server. Linked servers r created & need to update all the SP with linked servers inorder to work again. The script I am looking for is just to find out which stored procedures are affected and need to be fixed manually. I hope I am able to answer you queries. Please share me the script as it would be great help for me.

Comment: @RobertSievers Thanks for your answer. thanks for sharing the script. But I still have a major problem and that is how to deal procedures with Input parameters?
Can u suggest me how do I pass dummy parameters to verify the stored procedures.

Comment: Larnu and Jeroen Mostert have already answered this.  I know of no way to programmatically tackle something like that.

Comment: @Larnu any help possible from you ? The code I have written in Answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could alter this script to cycle through all DBs and UNION the results together.  This probably needs some adjustments to handle procedures of the same name within different schemas.

This cycles through all stored procedures and checks for their validity in terms of referencing other views, tables, column names and so forth.

```
USE my_db_name
GO

DECLARE @procedure AS VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @exec_err INT
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @procedure_list TABLE (
    name NVARCHAR(200),
    valid int
    );

IF CURSOR_STATUS('global', 'ListOfProcedures') >= -1
BEGIN
    CLOSE ListOfProcedures
    DEALLOCATE ListOfProcedures
END

INSERT INTO @procedure_list
SELECT 
    '[' + s.name + '].[' + p.name + ']' AS full_procedure_name,
    1 as valid
FROM sys.procedures p
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER By s.name, p.name

--SELECT * FROM @procedure_list

DECLARE ListOfProcedures CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT name FROM @procedure_list

OPEN ListOfProcedures 

FETCH NEXT FROM ListOfProcedures 
into @procedure 

SET NOCOUNT ON
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1) 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @statement = 'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule ''' + @procedure + ''''
        EXEC @exec_err = sp_executesql @stmt = @statement
        PRINT 'Procedure ' + @procedure + 'is ok'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'INVALID PROCEDURE FOUND: recorded dependency error in : ' + @procedure
        UPDATE @procedure_list
            SET valid = 0 
            WHERE name = @procedure
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM ListOfProcedures 
    INTO @procedure 

END 
SET NOCOUNT OFF

CLOSE ListOfProcedures; 
DEALLOCATE ListOfProcedures;

SELECT name
FROM @procedure_list
WHERE valid = 0
```

Comment: FYI `'[' + value + ']'` isn't injection safe. you should really be using `QUOTENAME`. Just like a literal string used instead of a parameter, a object can be used to inject too.

Comment: @Larnu.  Thank you for that suggestion.  I will check that out.  Most of the script I write are used by me and me only, but this is an area I need to learn more about.

Comment: `Declare listofparameter cursor fast_forward for
select
  parameterdatatype
from
  parametertable
where
  procedure = @procedure 
  open listofparameter 
  fetch next from listofparameter into @passparameter 
  while @ @fetch_status = 0 
  Begin 
  if(@passparameter = 'varchar')
set
  @parameter = 'abc'.........till all the available datatypes 
  fetch next
from
  listofparameter into @passparameter 
  End `
@Larnu I want to execute all the SP with above dummy values. Could u pls help how to write the logic. Also, i want to log the error caused by the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @procfunctable as table (dbname varchar(64),schemaname varchar(128),
storedprocname varchar(128),
[type] varchar(10),parameterid varchar(128),
parametername varchar(128),parameterdatatype varchar(128),
isoutputparameter int)
insert into @procfunctable
execute sp_MSforeachdb N'use ?; SELECT ''?'',
schema_name(schema_id) as schemaname,SO.name,
SO.type,coalesce(P.parameter_id,0) as [ParameterID],
coalesce(P.name,''NO PARAMETER'') as [ParameterName],
type_name(P.user_type_id),P.is_output
from sys.all_objects as SO
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.parameters as P
ON SO.Object_id=P.object_id
where so.object_id in (select object_id
from sys.objects where type in(''P'',''FN'')
and is_ms_shipped=0
and not exists(
select ep.[major_id]
from [sys].[extended_properties] ep
where ep.[major_id]=SO.[object_id]
and ep.[minor_id]=0
and ep.[class]=1
and ep.[name]=N''microsoft_database_tools_support'')
)
order by [schemaname],so.name,P.parameter_id'
--select * from @procfunctable

declare @viewstable as table (dbname varchar(64),schemaname varchar(128),
viewname varchar(128),
[type] varchar(20))
insert into @viewstable
execute sp_MSforeachdb N'use ?; SELECT ''?'',
schema_name(schema_id) as schemaname,SO.name,
so.type
from sys.all_objects as so
where so.object_id in (select object_id from sys.objects where type in (''V'')
and is_ms_shipped=0)
order by [schemaname],so.name'
--select * from @viewstable

declare @finaletable as table (dbname varchar(64),schemaname varchar(128),
objectname varchar(128),
[objecttype] varchar(128),result varchar(128),
errormessage varchar(4000))
insert into @finaletable
select dbname,schemaname,storedprocname,
case type
when 'p' then 'SQL stored procedure'
when 'FN' then 'SQL scalar function'
end as type,
null,'no error'
from @procfunctable
where dbname not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','dba')

insert into @finaletable select dbname,schemaname,viewname,'view',null,'no error'
from @viewstable where dbname not in ('master','tempdb','model','msdb','dba')

--select * from @finaletable

declare listofobjects cursor fast_forward
for
select dbname,schemaname,objectname,objecttype
from @finaletable
order by [objecttype]

declare @dbname varchar(128),@schemaname nvarchar(4000),@objectname 
nvarchar(4000),@objecttype nvarchar(4000),@result nvarchar='';

open listofobjects

fetch next from listofobjects into @dbname,@schemaname,@objectname,@objecttype
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
if(@objecttype='SQL stored procedure' or @objecttype='SQL scalar function')
begin
declare listofparameters cursor fast_forward
for
select dbname,parametername,parameterdatatype,isoutputparameter,parameterid from 
@procfunctable
where storedprocname=@objectname and dbname=@dbname and schemaname=@schemaname

declare @statement nvarchar(500)='',@parametername nvarchar(4000),@isoutputparameter 
nvarchar(4000),@paramtype varchar(100),@parameterid nvarchar(40),@errormessge 
nvarchar(max);

open listofparameters

fetch next from listofparameters into 
@dbname,@parametername,@paramtype,@isoutputparameter,@parameterid

DECLARE @parameter nvarchar(4000)='',@outputparamdeclare 
nvarchar(4000)='',@outputparameter nvarchar(4000)='',@paramdefinition 
nvarchar(4000)='',@parametersetting nvarchar(4000)='',@date nvarchar(200)='20170619'
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin
if(@parameter='varchar' and @isoutputparameter=0)
set @parameter =@parameter+'''abcd'','
else if(@parameter='int' and @isoutputparameter=0)
set @parameter =@parameter+'''23'','
else if (@objecttype='SQL stored procedure' and @isoutputparameter=1)
begin
set @outputparamdeclare=@outputparamdeclare+'declare '+'@parameter'+@parameterid+' 
'+@paramtype + char(10)
set @parameter=@parameter + '@parameter' + @parameterid +' '+'output, '
end
fetch next from listofparameters into 
@dbname,@parametername,@paramtype,@isoutputparameter,@parameterid
end

begin try
set @parameter=
case @parameter when null then null
else (
case len(@parameter) when 0 then @parameter
else left(@parameter,len(@parameter)-1)
end
)end

set @outputparamdeclare=
case @outputparamdeclare when null then null
else (
case len(@outputparamdeclare) when 0 then @outputparamdeclare
else left(@outputparamdeclare,len(@outputparamdeclare)-1)
end
)end

set @outputparameter =
case @outputparameter when null then null
else (
case len(@outputparameter) when 0 then @outputparameter
else left(@outputparameter,len(@outputparameter)-1)
end
)end

if(@objecttype='SQL stored procedure'and @isoutputparameter=0)
begin
declare @sqlquery nvarchar(4000),@sqlquerywithparameter nvarchar(4000);
set @sqlquery='['+@dbname+']'+'.'+'['+@schemaname+']'+'.'+'['+@objectname+']'
set 
@sqlquerywithparameter='['+@dbname+']'+'.'+'['+@schemaname+']'+'
.'+'['+@objectname+']'+' 
'+@parameter
--set @statement=N'EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule '''+@sqlquery+'''';
--execute @result=sp_executesql @statement
execute @result=sp_executesql @sqlquerywithparameter
end
else if (@objecttype='SQL stored procedure' and @isoutputparameter=1)
begin
set @statement='exec '+'['+@dbname+']'+'.'+'['+@schemaname+']'+'.
'+'['+@objectname+']'+' '+@parameter
declare @finalstatement varchar(max);
set @finalstatement=@outputparamdeclare+';'+@statement;
execute(@finalstatement)
end
else if (@objecttype='SQL scalar function' and @isoutputparameter=0)
begin
declare @funcquerywithparam nvarchar(max),@funcquery nvarchar(max),@command 
nvarchar(max);
set @funcquerywithparam='['+@dbname+']'+'.'+'['+@schemaname+']'+'
.'+'['+@objectname+']'+' '+@parameter
set @funcquery='['+@dbname+']'+'.'+'['+@schemaname+']'+'.'+'['+@objectname+']'

execute @result=sp_executesql @funcquerywithparam
end
else if(@paramtype is null and @isoutputparameter is null)
begin
set @result=1
update @finaletable
set errormessage='no parameter available'
where objectname=@objectname
end
update @finaletable
set result=@result
where objectname=@objectname
end try
begin catch
update @finaletable
set errormessage=ERROR_MESSAGE(),result=1
where objectname=@objectname
end catch
close listofparameters
deallocate listofparameters
end
if (@objecttype='view')
begin
begin try
declare @viewquery nvarchar(max),@viewname nvarchar(max)
set @viewname=@dbname+'.'+@schemaname+'.'+@objectname
set @viewquery='select top 1 * from '+@viewname
execute @result=sp_executesql @viewquery
update @finaletable
set result=@result
where objectname=@objectname
end try
begin catch
print'error found in '+@objectname
update @finaletable
set errormessage=ERROR_MESSAGE(),result=1
where objectname=@objectname
end catch
end
fetch next from listofobjects into @dbname,@schemaname,@objectname,@objecttype
end
close listofobjects
deallocate listofobjects

select distinct dbname,schemaname,objectname,[objecttype],
case result
when 0 then 'pass'
when 1 then 'fail'
end as result,
errormessage
from @finaletable
order by [objecttype]
set nocount off
```